# Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor }\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-i}{n \choose 2i}{n-2i \choose 2j}2^{n-2i-2j}=4^{n-1}+2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

I was working on problem 1 from the IMC 2020 and got the following expression for the solution:

$ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor }\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-i}{n \choose 2i}{n-2i \choose 2j}2^{n-2i-2j} $

The official solution is $ 4^{n-1}+2^{n-1}$. After plugging in some values and going over my solution, I determined they are equivalent. Is there an algebraic or combinatorial way to demonstrate that these two expressions are equivalent?

**(IMC Problem)**

Let $ n $ be a positive integer. Compute the number of words $ w $ (finite sequences of letters) that satisfy all the following three properties:

1. $ w $ consists of $ n $ letters, all of them are from the alphabet $\{a,b,c,d\}$.
2. $ w $ contains an even number of letters $ a $.
3. $ w $ contains an even number of letters $ b $.

**(Problem Solution)**

First, I only thought about cases where there were an even amount of one specific letter. The probability of there being $ k $ "a"s (WLOG look at $ a $) was $ Pr(k)={n \choose k} \left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^k \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{n-k} $.

Multiplying this by the total number of possible words $ 4^{n} $ gave $ A(k)={n \choose k} \left(3\right)^{n-k} $. To get the total even, I had to sum over whenever $ k $ was even, so

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}A\left(2k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}}{n \choose 2k}3^{n-2k} $$

Next, I tried to find an equivalent function for two variables and got

$$ A\left(i,j\right)={n \choose i}{n-i \choose j}\cdot2^{n-i-j} $$

because there are $ n $ spots for the first $ i $ letters to go, $ n-i $ spots for the next $ j $, and there are 2 possible letters for each other spot (with $ n-i-j $ other spots).

Now, I needed to sum all possible even combinations. The first thing I thought of was

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}A\left(2i,2j\right) $$

but this counts impossible cases, so I had to limit $ j $ so that the maximum sum was less than $ n $ and got

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-i}A\left(2i,2j\right) $$

or

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-i}{n \choose 2i}{n-2i \choose 2j}2^{n-2i-2j} $$

**Update**

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor }\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-i}{n \choose 2i}{n-2i \choose 2j} $$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}{n \choose 2i}{n-2i \choose 2j}2^{n-2i-2j} $$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-2i}{n \choose 2i}{n-2i \choose 2j}2^{n-2i-2j} $$

Factor

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose 2i}\sum_{j=0}^{n-2i}{n-2i \choose 2j}2^{n-2i-2j} $$

Now looking at the second sum, replace $ n-2i $ with $ k $ to get

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{k}{k \choose 2j}2^{k-2j} $$

which equals $ \frac{3^{k}+1}{2} $. Plugging back in gives

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose 2i}\frac{3^{n-2i}+1}{2} $$ After distributing, you have

$$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose 2i}*3^{n-2i}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose 2i} $$

Simplifying to

$$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose 2i}3^{n-2i}+2^{n-2} $$

If someone can help me solve that first sum, I believe the proof will be complete.

Comment: What did you try? As a hint: $\sum_{k= 0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor} \binom{m}{2k}x^{2k} = \sum_{ i \in [0:m], \textrm{ and even}} \binom{m}{i} x^i$ (why?). Does this remind you somewhat of a standard result? How can you adapt that to account for the even condition in the sum?

Comment: Binomial theorem. Specifically the expression (x+1)^m. When summing over the even terms only the even degrees are kept. 

Look at $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}{n \choose i}{n-i \choose j}2^{\left(n-i-j\right)}$

Factor and looking at the inside
$\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}{n-i \choose j}2^{n-i-j}$

Setting k = n-i and looking at the binomial expression version it's equal to 3^k or 3^n-i making the original 

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}3^{n-i}$ which is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}3^{i}$ which similarly is 4^n

This is a similar question but I don't see how to apply it to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing we start from

$$\sum_{p=0}^n
\frac{1}{2} (1+(-1)^p)
\sum_{q=0}^{n-p} \frac{1}{2} (1+(-1)^q)
{n\choose p} {n-p\choose q}
2^{n-p-q} = 4^{n-1} + 2^{n-1}.$$

This is

$$\sum_{p=0}^n
(1+(-1)^p) {n\choose p}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-p} (1+(-1)^q)
{n-p\choose q}
2^{n-p-q} = 4^n + 2^{n+1}.$$

The LHS becomes

$$\sum_{p=0}^n
(1+(-1)^p) {n\choose p} 2^{n-p}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-p} (1+(-1)^q) {n-p\choose q} 2^{-q}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n
(1+(-1)^p) {n\choose p} 2^{n-p}
((3/2)^{n-p}+(1/2)^{n-p})
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n
(1+(-1)^p) {n\choose p}
(3^{n-p}+1^{n-p}).$$

We obtain

$$4^n + 2^n + 2^n + 0 = 4^n + 2^{n+1}$$

as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Statement**

Let’s do a minor change to the problem statement: instead of using alphabets $\{a,b,c,d\}$ we use $\{a,b,c,e\}$. Same condition, we want even numbers of $a$ and $b$.

**Calculation**

First, we choose $m$ vowels and $n-m$ consonants. The number of possibilities is

$$
\binom{n}{m}
\phantom{x}
\forall
\phantom{x}
m\in [0,n]
$$

Then, we select an even number of vowels to be $a$. The number of possibilities is

$$
2^{m-1}
$$

if $m$ is nonzero or $1$ if $m=0$. Then we select an even number of consonants to be $b$. The number of possibilities is

$$
2^{n-m-1}
$$

if $m\neq n$ and $1$ if $m=n$.

**Results**

The number of possibilities is given by the following:

$$
\binom{n}{0}\cdot 1 \cdot 2^{n-1}+
\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{m}\cdot 2^{m-1}\cdot 2^{n-m-1}+
\binom{n}{n}\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot 1
$$

Substitute $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{m}=2^{n}-2$, do some algebra, then you will get $4^{n-1}+2^{n-1}$